# Kernel panic error when trying to install Xubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kernel, panic

I'm trying to install Xubuntu and ran into a roadblock. I keep receiving a wall of text with a message saying:
End Kernel panic-not synching: VFS: unable to mount root FS on unknown-block(0,0).

[image]

So far I've tried enabling the Windows Hypervisor and Virtual Machine platforms as per a tutorial I found but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.